# Range out of value in gamma fn, how to calculate factorial >200

Tags: r, binomial-coefficients, gamma-distribution

I am attempting to create a function to calculate the binomial formula, but I keep getting the error "Range out of value in gamma fn"

```
mything <- function(x, n, p) {
  a = choose(n, x)
  b = p^x
  c = (1 - p)^(n - x)
  d = a * b * c
  return(d)
}

mything(20, 2000, 0.01)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't give any error.

Comment: That code throws no error.

Comment: There is a standard R function for this: `dbinom(20,2000,0.01)`